# UWP C# - Setting the Language for InputInjector Keyboard

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I have an UWP app with simple on-screen keyboard using Buttons, it uses InputInjector class to send keys when the buttons are pressed, I've made a function for sending a key:

```
public void SendKey(ushort keyCode)
    {
        InjectedInputKeyboardInfo inputInfo = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
        InjectedInputKeyboardInfo myinput = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();

        myinput.VirtualKey = keyCode;

        var injector = InputInjector.TryCreate();

        injector.InjectKeyboardInput(new List<InjectedInputKeyboardInfo> { myinput });
    }
```

How would I specify which language? Currently it takes the system language but the app runs in full screen and the user cannot change the system language.

For example: `SendKey((ushort)'E')` would send E if the system language is English, if its not English then whatever the E key represents in the other language. I would like a way to change the language using code, not by using the Windows 10 language bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change this behavior. `InputInjector`'s purpose is to simulate actual key presses it doesn't simulate "characters". So when the user has set English keyboard, the key presses you simulate will match the English keyboard.

Actually you could even simulate the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> keyboard shortcut to switch the user's current language to the next in her language list :-D . The point is, you are simulating the hardware itself, but not how it is interpreted.